# How to convert time to time format in logstash

Tags: logstash

I want to ask that how to convert below time formats in logstash.

```
9:48:42 to 09:48:42
9:8:42 to 09:08:42
9:48:2 to 09:48:02
9:8:2 to 09:08:02
```

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question with this way;

> Creating input codec plugin and check if it starts without "0" then
> put it in front of the message (event) with ruby